# Why is my app's performance much lower when running it outside of development environment?

Tags: flash, flash-cs6, flashdevelop

I'm writing a game application in ActionScript 3. I use FlashDevelop to write the code and compiling and Flash CS-6 for visuals, etc.

The issue I'm having is with getting the program to run at a steady 60 FPS. When compiling and running the game in DEBUG through FlashDevelop, the framerate is pretty bad with serious drops when interacting. But when compiling and running the game in RELEASE through FlashDevelop the framerate is actually fine and close to a constant 60 FPS.

However once I run the game from Windows explorer, either the .exe or .swf version that has been cooked the framerate is as bad again as when running the game in DEBUG mode through the IDE. When running the .swf through a browser's flash plugin the framerate seems to be fine.

Framerate is fine when running the SWF through Firefox, MS Edge or Internet Explorer.

Framerate is bad when running SWF through standalone projector. I've tried multiple versions, including 32 (latest) and 16.

The .exe seems to incorporate version 11 of the projector and also has a bad framerate.

Is the projector just so badly optimized or am I doing something wrong? With Flash slowly losing support I had hoped I wouldn't have to rely on Browser plugins to run the game. Since the game runs fine in the IDE I expected that it would do too in the projector.

Comment: First of all, try the latest Flash Player executable. FP11 is a **VERY** outdated version. Grab a guide how to install the newest AIR SDK here (there's a chapter on CS6): https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/enable-the-latest-air-sdk-in-flash-professional-cs55--active-11488 Install newer StandAlone Projector on your system as well. If that won't help, then you're up for profiling your game and Adobe Scout is your friend.

Comment: Thank you, based on your reply I first upgraded the projector and made the .exe use FlashPlayer 32 (latest), this however had no effect on improving the framerate.

I then figured it must be an issue with the projector in general and opted to set up publishing to an Adobe AIR application, which took some figuring out, but solves the framerate issue.

I now have a smooth running .exe file! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue was to use Adobe AIR instead of the flash projector. It solved all performance issues.